# What are downsides of Israel's starting war on Iran?

Tags: armed-conflict, israel, iran, middle-east

Influenced by [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/68027/will-not-diplomacy-and-negotiations-with-the-iranian-regime-weaken-israel) question, now been deleted. In that question its author in rude and abusive form asked about why Israel still not bombing Iran.

I wonder what downsides (other than massacring civilians, which is a usual side effect of air strikes) can such attack have?

Comment: Related question: [What are “pluses” of Israel starting a war with Iran?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/68029/what-are-pluses-of-israel-starting-a-war-with-iran)

Comment: Frankly both this and your other question are pretty badly framed. By several accounts, Israel *is* engaged in a low-intensity/"shadow" war with Iran already. https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-08-04/understanding-the-shadow-war-between-israel-and-iran-quicktake ; https://moderndiplomacy.eu/2020/12/04/iran-israel-can-the-low-intensity-conflict-turn-into-open-war/ So it's not too clear to me what your idea of "starting war" is...

Comment: If you're thinking of a more obvious attack like the airstrikes conducted against [Iraq's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Opera) and [Syrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Outside_the_Box) [alleged] nuclear facilities in the past, please make the Qs more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One downside is that a regional war between Israel and Iran is likely to escalate to include other countries and military organizations in the region:

1. Hezbollah - the Lebanese political party and military organization - is considered the Iranian local henchman. It will most certainly respond to an Israeli military initiative against Iran. This will prompt an Israeli response and soon we will witness a 3rd round of an Israeli-Lebanese war.
2. Hamas, The de-facto ruler of Gaza strip, has long been [receiving military aid from Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karine_A_affair) and may find it beneficial to join Hezbollah and attack Israel with its now-usual MO of rocket barrages and/or exploding balloons and/or attack from tunnels.

Furthermore, any regional conflict runs the risk of forcing involvement of the world powers, since they all have invested interests in the area and compete for dominance:

1. [Iran has recently signed a pact agreement with China](https://www.arabnews.com/node/1832691/middle-east)
2. Russia and Iran share a common enemy in the form of USA. They also have cooperated in supporting the Syrian president, Assad, in the Syrian civil war. Following the western sanctions, Iran's Air Force [is increasingly becoming Russian built](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Russia_relations#Current_relations)

Comment: The EU might not be too happy either. Judging by the JCPOA, their goal seems to be to reintegrate Iran into the international community, not antagonize them even further. But they can't afford to oppose Israel either. Being forced to take sides in a hypothetical Israel/Iran war would put the EU into a very difficult position.

Answer (score 5):

There are many reasons why going to war is a bad idea in general: starting a war is easy but ending it is hard. There are several examples in the past few decades showing that even vastly superior military power does not guarantee a good outcome for the attacking country, e.g. Afghanistan, Yemen.

The main problem is: what would be the goal of this war? Even considering the very optimistic scenario where Israel succeeds militarily and there is no escalation of the conflict with other countries, what happens next? Is Israel going to occupy Iran, a 1.6m km² country with 83m inhabitants? And then, is it going to establish a new non-theocratic government in Iran? Or annex it and give Israeli citizenship to all Iranians? Once one starts thinking about what happens in the long term, it's hard to find a scenario  which would lead to a positive outcome for Israel.

Answer (score -5):

The downside would be the loss of an extremely useful bogeyman. For the same reason even the fall of the current regime would be a curse for the US and Israel.